# java sandbox project ready to test?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm introducing myself in the java world and springsource seems to be the most important community for this language. My background come from C# with MS products mainly, despite I worked with LAMP environment in the past.

Based on the fact that I`m starting to approach into the java world I was wondering if any mvc framework -eg: springsource- is offering a sandbox project environment. I mean a tutorial with a previously created project including security - roles, users - in order to fast deploy test in localhost and have a first impression of these proposals.

Examples in other languages:

- [PHP](http://www.symfony-project.org/doc/1_4/)
- [symfony offers docs & prepackaged project to test](http://symfony-reloaded.org/code)
- [C# has its nerddinner tutorial](http://www.nerddinner.com/) [with code](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) and [tutorial](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - for spring-mvc + spring security - the [petclinic application](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html). The link I provided discusses how to add security to the original petclinic, which demonstrates all aspects of spring-mvc

Comment: Bozho, thank you so much!. I will check this app. When I checked spring I only found a set up project. brgds.!